# Need to delete Files from Multiple directorys chosen by user inputs. shutil.rmtree()

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

Hey guys Im trying to make a simple program which cleans up directorys gathered by user input. AKA User inputs "E:" for deleting and "F:" for deleting. But I cant get it to work Using shutil.

I cant seem to find a way to store the user inputs in a way which lets shutil use it for deleting!

Im really new to python and programming in general so im probably doing some stupid mistake.

EDIT: I need it so The user inputs gets stored in a form of list, then I can run shutil to delete all the directoris stored in the list

```
import shutil
DeleteThis = {}

def DirectoryToDelete():
    DirectoryToEnter = input('Enter Filepath of directory you want to delete: ')
    DeleteThis.append(DirectoryToEnter)
    print (DeleteThis)

shutil.rmtree(DeleteThis)
```

Comment: Why use a set (or list for that matter) if you are only deleting one directory? Also the `append` method is used for lists. Sets use add

Answer (score 0):

Use string for shutil and check your directory with [os.path.isdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir):

```
import shutil
import os.path

while True:
    directory = input('Enter Filepath of directory you want to delete: ')
    if os.path.isdir(directory):
        shutil.rmtree(directory)
        print "Directory was deleted!"
    else:
        print "Bad directory"
```

Comment: Also, if you are using linux you can get tab completion on the input by inserting `readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")` before `input` (and import readline).

Comment: Want to modify your answer to add multiple directories in one input or some way of exiting loop without `KeyboardInterrupt`? Also `input` is python-3.x while print statement is python-2.x

Answer (score 0):

A modification of JRazors answer:

```
import shutil
import os.path
import readline

#allow tab completion in input
readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete") 

delete_this = input('Enter Directories you want to delete separated by comma: ')
for d in delete_this.split(','):
    d=d.strip()
    if os.path.isdir(d):
        shutil.rmtree(d)
        print("{} deleted".format(d))
```

This looks through the text separated by comma to find directories you want to delete.

Use example

```
python delete_dir.py 
Enter Directories you want to delete separated by comma: fo<tab>
foo1/       foo2/       foo3.txt  
Enter Directories you want to delete separated by comma: foo1,foo2
foo1 deleted
foo2 deleted
```